# different content, same url, bad for SEO?

Tags: seo

I want to translate the page based on the accept-language headers, do I need to redirect to /$lang or having different content(actually same content but translated) in the same url is ok?

Comment: Because it is a different language, I would say you would not be penalised for duplicate content, especially as it is the same URL.